# How to convert Object to JSON/string which uses mixed-character-indexes its arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, object

I have an `object` (vue proxy) which looks like this when **logged by itself**:

```
Proxy {5eda71599cdbb8: {…}}
    [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Array(0)
        5eda71599cdbb8:
            float: "none"
            size: "small"
            src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA...
    [[Prototype]]: Object
        length: 0
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

But when I try to `JSON.stringify` the object, it just returns an empty array:

```
[]
```

How do I convert the `whole object's` data (`Array(0)`):

```
5eda71599cdbb8: {
    float: "none"
    size: "small"
    src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA...
}
```

into a transportable `text` format like `JSON`? What is important is that the `whole object` is converted because in production it will have more than one array, so just putting the array into a variable is not enough. The object has to stay intact, since it's a `reactive storage entity`.

It seems that the `object` doesn't "see" the array, showing that the length is 0 -> `Array(0)`. The `array key` that is `5eda71599cdbb8` might be the cause.

Comment: Only integer keys of the array are included in the length.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` what is the type of this object? Is it a ref, a computed property?

Comment: Your target should be an object and not an array

Comment: the fact that `length: 0` possibly means that you think the array has something in it when it does not - the value shown in the console is evaluated when you inspect the object, not when it is logged

Comment: @superdunck it returns `nothing` when logged with a string. The object is a `reactive state object` of vue.

Comment: @adiga The object carries an array of objects.

Comment: seems like it is an instance of class Proxy. is it coming from any class btw ?